# Audio/Video out of sync when recording

Tags: ffmpeg

I am recording the desktop with gdigrab and the audio with dshow, but they are out of sync.

This is the first thing I tried, there was always about the same delay (about 20-30 frames):

```
// Command
ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="Microphone (NVIDIA RTX Voice)" -f gdigrab -framerate 60 -offset_x 0 -offset_y 0 -video_size 1920x1080 -i desktop -c:v h264 -preset ultrafast -qp 0 C:\Videos\test2.mp4

// Bottom of debug log
Input file #0 (audio=Microphone (NVIDIA RTX Voice)):
  Input stream #0:0 (audio): 15 packets read (1323000 bytes); 15 frames decoded (330750 samples);
  Total: 15 packets (1323000 bytes) demuxed
Input file #1 (desktop):
  Input stream #1:0 (video): 223 packets read (1849663242 bytes); 223 frames decoded;
  Total: 223 packets (1849663242 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (C:\Videos\test2.mp4):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 243 frames encoded; 243 packets muxed (211227447 bytes);
  Output stream #0:1 (audio): 322 frames encoded (329728 samples); 323 packets muxed (120103 bytes);
  Total: 566 packets (211347550 bytes) muxed
238 frames successfully decoded, 0 decoding errors
[AVIOContext @ 0000028163c9c040] Statistics: 2 seeks, 810 writeouts
```

The second thing I tried I believe fixed the audio sync issue, but I can really tell because it made the recording very laggy:

```
// Command
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 60 -offset_x 0 -offset_y 0 -video_size 1920x1080 -i desktop -f dshow -i audio="Microphone (NVIDIA RTX Voice)" -c:v h264 -preset ultrafast -qp 0 C:\Videos\test2.mp4

// Bottom of debug log
Input file #0 (desktop):
  Input stream #0:0 (video): 112 packets read (928978848 bytes); 112 frames decoded;
  Total: 112 packets (928978848 bytes) demuxed
Input file #1 (audio=Microphone (NVIDIA RTX Voice)):
  Input stream #1:0 (audio): 12 packets read (1058400 bytes); 12 frames decoded (264600 samples);
  Total: 12 packets (1058400 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (C:\Videos\test2.mp4):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 388 frames encoded; 388 packets muxed (109408287 bytes);
  Output stream #0:1 (audio): 258 frames encoded (264192 samples); 259 packets muxed (96404 bytes);
  Total: 647 packets (109504691 bytes) muxed
124 frames successfully decoded, 0 decoding errors
[AVIOContext @ 0000019da713c040] Statistics: 2 seeks, 421 writeouts
```

How can I sync the audio and video?

It turns out it is only the microphone that has the delay, I tried using `virtual-audio-capturer` device and the audio synced perfectly, but that is only the desktop audio and not the mic.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the device from RTX to your actual Device.

Comment: I did, the delay was still there.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions:

1. using dshow screen-capture-recorder instead of gdigrab

ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="screen-capture-recorder":audio="Your-Microphone" output.mkv

2. or set an offset value for either video or audio which is a little bit faster

put -itoffset 00:00:0.6 (eg. 600ms)behind whichever is faster

Comment: I get `Unrecognized option 'itoffset'` when I write `ffmpeg -y -f dshow -rtbufsize 10M -i audio=%mic% -itoffset 00:00:0.6 ......`, `%mic%` is a string of my microphone.